# How can a Node.js readable stream be duplicated and consumed independently?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to duplicate or tee a Node.js readable stream so that the streams can be consumed independently from the same source?

My use case looks something like this:

```
f(inputStream, callback(err, data) {
  // do stuff with data to change how g behaves
  g(inputStream);
});
```

The requirement is that `f` and `g` start reading from the beginning of the stream. I would normally use [`readable.pipe`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) here but `g` needs to happen in the callback.

Comment: What kind of stream is that `inputStream`?

Comment: It's a readable stream, but in my actual use-case it's a multipart upload.

Comment: If `f()` consumes the stream entirely, you could use [`streamifier`](https://github.com/gagle/node-streamifier) to create a new readable stream to pass to `g()`.

Answer (score -3):

You can pass the same readable stream to both f and g. They will read from the stream independent of one another.

For example:-

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.createReadStream('<file location>');


function f(s) {
s.on('data', function (d) {
        console.log(d.toString());
});
s.on('end', function() {
        console.log('ended');
});
}
function g(s) {
s.on('data', function (d) {
        console.log(d.toString());
});
s.on('end', function() {
        console.log('ended');
});
}

g(str);
f(str);
```